# ¿Cómo retornar a un elemento de un objeto JSON?

Tags: php, laravel

¿Cómo muestro solo el elemento `direccion` que vienen de la base de datos ?

```
function mostrarusuario()
{

    $usuario = User::all();

    // he probadoa asi pero me da error
    return response()->json($usuario['direccion']); 
}
```

Comment: Hola, deberías añadir algo más de información: ¿qué error recibes? ¿qué es `response`? ¿cuál es la estructura de `$usuario`? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio.

Comment: Esto es incorrecto, `$usuario` es un colección ya que eso es lo que retorna `All()`, es imposible acceder de esa forma. ¿Desea obtener la dirección de un solo usuario? ¿Qué usuario sería? O todas las direcciones de su tabla.

Comment: Solo la dirección de un usuario ya que en la base de datos solo tengo un solo usuario

Comment: Entonces debería ser simplemente `$usuario = User::find(1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comente, el método `All()` como su nombre nos da a entender , traerá todos lo registros de nuestra tabla , al ser así no retorna un `objeto` **si no una colección** la cuál es imposible acceder tal cuál lo está haciendo.

Como comenta que solo tiene un solo usuario , tal cuál está podría acceder como si fuese un `array` , por su indice **0**  . *(El acceso orientado a objetos)* **->**

```
$usuario = User::all();
return response()->json($usuario[0]->direccion);
```

O algunos métodos más sencillo que si retornan un objeto `first` o `firstOrFail` este último retornará un 404 cuando no encuentre lo deseado

```
 $usuario = User::firstOrFail();
return response()->json($usuario->direccion);
```

O `find` parecido a `findOrFail` , este último también retorna un 404 al no encontrar el registro

```
//$usuario = User::find(1); //Buscará el id 1
$usuario = User::findOrFail(1); //Buscará el id 1
return response()->json($usuario->direccion);
```

Answer (score 1):

He ido a hacer un pequeño ejemplo, y te comento que esta es mi opción de solución:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
  public function list($id)
  {
      $posts = Post::findOrFail($id);
      //dd($posts);
      return response()->json($posts['title']);
  }
}
```

Solo sería cuestión lo adaptes a tus necesidades, espero ayude

Ya lo he probado con ids que paso por la URL en forma de parametros y es funcional